# Why this particular xml parsing code works for small xml, but fails for large xml?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml.etree

I have a function for parsing xml content, like below:

```
def parse_individual_xml(self, xml_url):
    xml_data_to_parse = urlopen(xml_url).read()
    jobs = ET.fromstring(xml_data_to_parse)
    return jobs
```

This function is working perfectly, until I was working with smaller file (1-2 mb). but when I have taken a large xml url, I got this error.

> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0

Afaik, it is some encoding-decoding issue.

the below function gives exactly same behavior.

```
def parse_individual_xml(self, xml_url):
    xml_data_to_parse = urlopen(xml_url)
    jobs = ET.parse(xml_data_to_parse).getroot()
    return jobs
```

Then I tried a bit differently.

I downloaded that large file locally, and changed the function like below:

```
def parse_individual_xml(self, xml_local_path):
    jobs = ET.parse(xml_local_path).getroot()
    return jobs
```

And, it works for any file, large or small. Eventually I will use `iterparse` of etree. but at first I want to know the reason of above mentioned behavior.

How can I solve them?

Comment: Line 1 column 0 suggests no data was returned by `urlopen`. Have you inspected the return value?

Comment: It would be helpful to *at least* show a sample of the data the server returns, as well as the relevant headers.

Comment: I was searching with the error message, which brings into some encoding decoding solution. I haven't examine the response properly :( But I got the point of both of you. Let me examine it. I will get back to you. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote server almost certainly is [*compressing* large responses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) using GZIP (or, less common, deflate).

Based on the `Content-Encoding` header, decompress the stream before trying to parse it:

```
import gzip

response = urlopen(xml_url)
if response.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
    # transparent decompression of a GZIP-ed response
    response = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=response)
jobs = ET.parse(response).getroot()
```

You may want to consider using the `requests` library instead, it can handle this for you, transparently. To *stream* the data into a iterative parser, use `stream=True`, access the `response.raw` file-like object and configure it to do transparent decompression:

```
response = requests.get(xml_url, stream=True)
response.raw.decode_content = True  # handle content-encoding compression
jobs = ET.parse(response.raw).getroot()  # or use iterparse
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Content encoding is `gzip`. I guess I can do it now. Thanks. 

One additional question, if the url itself serves a xml.gz, will the scenerio  be same as above? And, can the request module handle this case internally?

Comment: It depends. Does the server give you a `Content-Encoding: gzip` response in that case, or a `Content-Type: application/gzip` or other content type header? If the latter, then no, it'll not be decompressed transparently, and you'd have to use the `GzipFile()` approach.

Comment: `Content-Type: application/x-gzip` :( . So, yeah I need to use `GzipFIle()` anyway. Thanks a lot man. Learnt a completely new thing today. I have never given `Content-Type` the proper attention it deserves. Will study about it definitely.